# Characters still matching even though regex says "don't match if the same character is behind/in front"

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match words between asterisks:

```
This is a *test.*
```

This is the regex:

```
\*(.*?)\*
```

But I don't want to match the word if it's surrounded by two or more asterisks:

```
This is a **test.**
```

So I updated the regex to reflect that:

```
(?<!\*)\*(.*?)\*(?!\*)
```

However, `**test**` is still being matched.

Why is this? And how to fix it?

https://regexr.com/4td9l

Comment: What's the code that you are using? According to my [tests](https://regex101.com/r/QTQ8d2/1), `test.` is not the one that's matched. What's being matched is the empty space between the asterisks in `**`.

Comment: Do I understand it right that you need to also match `**` capturing empty space btween the two `*`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` matches anything (except newlines) `.*?` may include `*`s - the matched substring is basically *expanding* to include the inner `*`s, while the outer `*`s are matching the `\*`s, so that the lookbehind and lookaheads are still fulfilled.

Change the inner group to not match `*`s:

```
(?<!\*)\*([^*]+)\*(?!\*)
         ^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/J6tUoL/1

Comment: I found out that the replacement part no longer works with this regex. The replacement part is: `<em>$1</em>`. It turns the original string to This is a <em>$1</em>

Comment: If you need the capturing group, then surround the character class in the capturing group

Answer (score 2):

If there is the possibility to match a double `**` between the single `*` you could double the lookarounds

```
(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)(.*?)(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sOKAdY/1)